# typeid and type_info class

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid

```
namespace std {
 class type_info
 {
 public:
  virtual ~type_info(); //type_info can serve as a base class
 // enable comparison
  bool operator==(const type_info& rhs ) const;
 // return !( *this == rhs)
  bool operator!=(const type_info& rhs ) const;
  bool before(const type_info& rhs ) const; // ordering
 //return a C-string containing the type's name
  const char* name() const;
 private:
  //objects of this type cannot be copied
     type_info(const type_info& rhs );
     type_info& operator=(const type_info& rhs);
 }; //type_info
}
```

In the declaration of type_info class ,I can't find any data member .So what is constructed or destructed ??  Also typeid isn't declared in it.So how type_info object is accessed by it?
Is above representation incomplete? **Please tell about the type of data member in `type_info` class**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at the public interface of `typeinfo` from C++03. The standard doesn't restrict an implementation from adding members to a standard class (so long as there names come from those reserved to the implementation) to make things work.

In the implementation that I am currently using `std::typeinfo` has a private member `const char* __name` which is used to implement the public member functions according to the requirements of the standard.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 17.5.2.3 Private members [objects.within.classes] / 1:

> Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D do not specify the representation of classes, and intentionally omit specification of class members (9.2). An implementation may define static or non-static class members, or both, as needed to implement the semantics of the member functions specified in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D.

Similar wording appears in C++03 17.3.2.3.

Comment: Is mechanism to get the type is  written  by compiler or author of c++ implement it

Comment: @10001001058: Your question isn't very clear to me. The mechanism to get the type has to be implemented by the author of the C++ implementation that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

`typeid` is a keyword, not a function, so it need not and cannot be declared. It cannot be a function, since then the expression `typeid(T)` where `T` is a type would not be valid. It is implemented in the compiler, not in the library.

`typeinfo` doesn't need to have any data members; its `name` method is allowed to serve strings from what is effectively a `static` array of them. For example, consider this simple class that knows its own name:

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
    // look ma, no data members!
  public:
    char const *name() const;
};

// foo.cpp
char const NAME[] = "Foo";
char const *Foo::name() const { return NAME; }
```

Apart from `name`, the main operation on `typeinfo` objects is `==`, which can be implemented by a simple pointer comparison between the objects; in that case, the compiler could construct a big `typeinfo []` array somewhere private and `typeid` would just index into that array to fetch the right `typeinfo` object. How it works, however, is implementation-dependent.

Comment: If you are asserting that `typeinfo` isn't allowed any additional members, you should probably explain how it knows which string to serve up through name.

Comment: @larsmans :could you please explain why "typeinfo doesn't need to have any data members" more broadly.thank you

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I'm saying `typeinfo` doesn't *need* to have additional members, not that it's not *allowed* to have them.

Comment: Without a data member, how would it know which string to serve from the static array? In your Foo example you can't have multiple instances serving different names, which is what type_info does. (You could use the address of the type_info as a key into some table - but why would you?)

Comment: @AlanStokes: yes, I was indeed thinking of fetching the index from its own address. If all `typeinfo` objects are in an array as well, then the pointer juggling involved is trivial. I was presuming the OP was looking at an actual header file; I only realized later that they were quoting from the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There are no data members you can access. `type_info` is implemented for you by the compiler; the details are not public. You obtain a `type_info` by using `typeid`.

Don't worry, it's the compiler's job to make it all work.